# How should I set a daily method as executed, from inside or from outside?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
static void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (BIGService bigService in runningServices)
    {
        if (!bigService.ExecutedToday)
        {
            int executionResult = bigService.Execute();
            string serviceName = bigService.ToString();
            if (executionResult == 0)
            {
                EventLogger.WriteToEventLog("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                EventLogger.WriteToEventLog("Failure");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where `BIGService` is an Abstract class, that has 5 descendants (5 individual service classes with this common parent).  The enclosing timer's interval is 7200. So it elapses in every 2 hours.

All services must be run only once a day. Therefore I created a `bool ExecutedToday` property and `void SetAsExecuted` method.

My question is: where do you recommend I should call the `SetAsExecuted` method? Which way is more subservient?  In the end of the `Execute()` method itself or in my copied code at the end of the `if` clause?

(Similar situations have happened to me several times, I just now have the time to ask other's opinion)

Comment: Why not just set up a Scheduled Task on the machine this needs to run under?

Comment: I don't really want to use that. I want my program to manage itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your code stands now it looks to me as if the timer has some responsibilities it shouldent have.

My suggestion would be to either move all the timer information to your timer, including bigService.ExecutedToday and SetAsExecuted OR you move all that logic inside the service. I would go for the latter since that would be more in line with the "Tell dont ask" principle.

The code in the timer would look like this:

```
static void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (BIGService bigService in runningServices)
    {            
           bigService.Execute();           
    }
}
```

In your BigService method you contain the logging and wether or not that service can be run at the time it is requested.

One more thing: I would make an Enum to store the 0 value for executionResult, at a later date it might not be clear to you what 0 actually means

Comment: Or `bool` instead of an Enum, if you want a boolean "succeeded-or-failed" result.

Comment: @CrisW Good point. If its a succeed/fail scenario there is really no need for an enum and a bool would give the desired clarity.

Comment: It's not an easy 1 bit scenario, there are more branches as results. Actually that is Enum, just here in this code is 0 (just for the sake of simplicity). Thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I prefer it if classes manage their own state as much as possible: that makes it difficult to use them incorrectly.

For example, in the code above you are able to 'forget' to call SetAsExecuted and can thus write a bug.

So if ExecutedToday is a property of Service then it's better if Service manages that property state.

```
Service
{
    DateTime recentlyExecuted;
    public bool ExecutedToday
    { get { return (DateTime.Now - recentlyExecuted) < new TimeSpan(1,0,0,0); } }
    public int Execute() {
        int executionResult = OnExecute(); // do the work
        if (executionResult == 0)
        {
            EventLogger.WriteToEventLog("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            EventLogger.WriteToEventLog("Failure");
        }
        recentlyExecuted = DateTime.Now; // or, only set if execution successful?
        return executionResult;
    }
    protected abstract int OnExecute(); // do subclass-specific work for Execute
}
```

If you want to ensure that Execute sets the property, then it should be a [template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) as coded above: otherwise (if Execute is abstract) then you're counting on every subclass to remember to set the property in its override of the Execute method.

Alternatively you can maintain the recentlyExecuted property outside the Service class:

```
static Map<BIGService, DateTime> recentlyExecuted = new Map<BIGService, DateTime>();

static void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (BIGService bigService in runningServices)
    {
        if (recentlyExecuted.ContainsKey(service) &&
            ((DateTime.Now - recentlyExecuted[service]) < new TimeSpan(1,0,0,0)))
            continue; // already executed today
        int executionResult = bigService.Execute();
        recentlyExecuted[service] = DateTime.Now; // or, only set if execution successful?
        string serviceName = bigService.ToString();
        if (executionResult == 0)
        {
            EventLogger.WriteToEventLog("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            EventLogger.WriteToEventLog("Failure");
        }
    }
}
```